# Making a thread Foreground VS Thread.Join()

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

If a `foreground thread` is a thread that prevents a process from terminating until all foreground threads belonging to the process have finished, and if the `Join` method Blocks the calling thread until a thread terminates, then what's really the difference between the two techniques ?

**Foreground Thread :**

```
static void Main()
    {
        Thread foregroundThread = 
            new Thread(new ThreadStart(SomeMethod));
        foregroundThread.Name = "ForegroundThread";

        foregroundThread.IsBackground = false;

        foregroundThread.Start();
    }
```

**Join() method :**

```
static void Main() 
    {
        Thread thread = 
                new Thread(new ThreadStart(SomeMethod));

        thread.Name = "Thread";
        thread.Start();
        thread.Join();
    }
```

Is there a difference between the two approaches ?

Comment: Makes no difference in this specific code snippet.  Which isn't very representative for real code that uses threads.  Sometimes you really do want to make sure that a thread is terminated without also terminating the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that when a process shuts down/exits/stops it needs all its foreground threads to stop before it can safely terminate. Your second code although it gives the same result as the first one, it differs in the way it behaves. `Join` blocks the execution of the your main thread which is a foreground thread of that process making it impossible to safely terminate the process unless your background thread finishes execution.

The main benefit of foreground threads comes when you try starting threads from another background thread.

Say you are trying to write a thread that writes vital data to disk and that thread gets started from a background thread. Now you need to make sure that if the user decides to close your process, that the thread writing the data will not abnormally terminate mid way before completing its designated task.

Imagine you have such a scenario:

```
static void Main()
{
   Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(SomeMethod));
   thread.IsBackground = true;
   backgroundThread.Start();
} 


static void SomeMethod() 
{
   Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(SomeOtherMethod));
   thread.Name = "ForegroundThread";
   thread.IsBackground = false;
   thread.Start();
}
```

Here although your main thread creates a background thread without a wait or join, your process will never exit until the foreground thread created by the background thread exits.

Comment: Is the code in this answer correct? It's really confusing: First-> BackGroundThread is a method and an object. Second-> BackgroundThread is not really a background thread because has not assigned IsBackground=true.

Comment: @Freerider nice catch, changed the name of the method to match the call. Hope it makes sense now.

Comment: Thank you Red Serpent for your quick response. I also added "backgroundThread.IsBackground = true;"

Comment: @Freerider setting IsBackground to true is redundant since all threads in .Net are background by default. I'm surprised that this got approved actually... I'll remove it

Comment: Hi Red Serpent. Are you sure about it? I have debugged the Thread creation and the "IsBackground" property is set to false by default. What is redundant is "thread.IsBackground = false;"

Comment: @Freerider oops, yes that is correct. Sorry for the confusion, haven't been getting much sleep lately :)

Comment: No problem! Thank you for fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is the concept of Fire and Forget.i.e. One does not wait for the end of the thread. If one calls the Join method then you are explicitly waiting for the thread to finish execution.